# AngularJS Hide selected items in the drop-down options

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to allocate two crews based on the same data from the server. In the drop-down options, when I select an item in one box. I would like the selected option to disappear in the next drop-down

Comment: You can call a function on ng-change of first drop-down in which you remove the previous value given to your next drop-down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a filter in the ngOptions expression:

Define your two select box like this , one with a filter

```
<select ng-model="crew1" ng-options="crew.text for crew in crews1></select>
<select ng-model="crew2" ng-options="crew.text for crew in crews2 | filter:shouldShow"></select>
```

and define the shouldShow() function to $scope in the controller:

```
$scope.shouldShow = function (crew) {
 // put your authorization logic here
  return $scope.crew1 != 'selectedOption';
}
```

Comment: The ng-options are being fed from the same array:

<div custom-select="CITTeller.crewId as CITTeller.fullName for CITTeller in searchAsyncx($searchTerm, 'Cashier')" custom-select-options="{ 'async': true }" ng-model="CITCrewAllocation.tellerId" required>

Comment: and the select boxes can be multiple, im getting the select boxes from an ng-repeat: ng-repeat="CITCrewAllocation in CITCrewAllocations"
this gets the number of select boxes, all feeding from the same array

Comment: Doesn't matters , ng-model values will be different , all that matters just add a filter and restrict ng-option value from displaying as shown above.
Hope it helps. :)